# How to keep sending progress for heavy APIs in HapiJS?

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I have implemented one heavy API using HapiJS a module of NodeJS. This API takes around 4-5 minutes for response. But in this case the client is showing 'Request Timeout' message. I want to send the progress to the client as keep-alive. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[timeout.server](http://hapijs.com/api/8.8.0#route-options) is what you need. It sets the maximum time allowed for the server to respond to an incoming client request. You can set the time accordingly and meanwhile show a progress bar in the front end to the client.

```
server.route({
 ...
 timeout: {
  server: 4500
 }
 ...
});
```